# How to set the checkpoint for fine-tuning

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I found the loss when I retrain the model(ssd_mobilenetv2) from model_zoo is very large at the begining of training, While the accuracy on validation_set is good. Training log as below:

The log couldn't be from the trained model. I doubt it doesn't load the checkpoint to do the fine-tune. Please help me how to do the fine-tune with the trained model on the same dataset. I didn't modify the network structure at all.

I set the checkpoint path in pipeline.config as below:
fine_tune_checkpoint:"**/**/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt"
If I set the model_dir as my downloaded directory, It wouldn't train since the global_train_step is larger than max_step. Then I enlarge the max_step, I can see the log of restoring the parameter from checkpoint. But it would meet error that couldn't restore some parameter.
So I set the model_dir to a empty directory. It could train normally but the loss in step0 would be very large. And the validation result is very bad

## in pipeline.config

```
fine_tune_checkpoint: "/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt"
num_steps: 200000
fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
```

## train script

```
model_dir = '/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/retrain0524

pipeline_config_path = '/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/pipeline.config'

checkpoint_dir = '/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt'

num_train_steps = 300000
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=model_dir)
train_and_eval_dict = model_lib.create_estimator_and_inputs(
    run_config=config,
    hparams=model_hparams.create_hparams(hparams_overrides),
    pipeline_config_path=pipeline_config_path,    
    sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=sample_1_of_n_eval_examples,
    sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples=(sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples))
estimator = train_and_eval_dict['estimator']
train_input_fn = train_and_eval_dict['train_input_fn']
eval_input_fns = train_and_eval_dict['eval_input_fns']
eval_on_train_input_fn = train_and_eval_dict['eval_on_train_input_fn']
predict_input_fn = train_and_eval_dict['predict_input_fn']
train_steps = train_and_eval_dict['train_steps']

train_spec, eval_specs = model_lib.create_train_and_eval_specs(
        train_input_fn,
        eval_input_fns,
        eval_on_train_input_fn,
        predict_input_fn,
        train_steps,
        eval_on_train_data=False)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
```

INFO:tensorflow:loss = 356.25497, step = 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 1.89768
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 11.221423, step = 100 (52.700 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2.21685
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 10.329516, step = 200 (45.109 sec)

Comment: It is better to have the complete config file pasted over here. For example, if the `from_checkpoint_type` is set to `classification`, some of the parameters won't restore to the checkpoint so the loss might be high in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks your reply, I just full the pipeline.config contents, The pipeline file wasn't be modified except for the path of dataset and labels after downloading from model zoo. Is there somewhere else I need to modify? And how could I know the model's parameter has been loaded?

Comment: What you can do is not using the checkpoint and simply training from scratch, then you can compare if there is any difference with the results when setting a checkpoint. I'd expect this time the training loss is much bigger (by several orders)

Comment: Thanks your suggestion. I remove the checkpoint and find the first loss is larger than 400. And there is a warning for not finding the checkpoint. I feel so confused why the first loss is so large although I've load checkpoint correctly.

Comment: I just set the val_step is 1 and learning rate is small enough. After loading the checkpoint. It will be validated every iter. But I found the AP is all zero. It indicates the pre-trained model is not loaded correctly.

Comment: If the number of classes is not the same as the number of classes from the model in the checkpoint, some variables in the predictor's scope won't be restored to the checkpoint anyway. This will cause the initial evaluation results to be bad.

Answer (score 1):

If the initial training loss is 400, the model most likely is restored from a checkpoint successfully, just not all the same as the checkpoint.

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/6fc642d423648f6a932673f0b3c07e40268c979f/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py#L1161) is the `restore_map` function of `ssd` models, note that even if you set `fine_tune_checkpoint_type : detection` and even provided with exactly the same model's checkpoint, still only the variables in the `feature_extractor` scope are restored. To restore as much variables from the checkpoint as possible, you will have to set `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true` in your config file.

```
def restore_map(self,
              fine_tune_checkpoint_type='detection',
              load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars=False):

if fine_tune_checkpoint_type not in ['detection', 'classification']:
  raise ValueError('Not supported fine_tune_checkpoint_type: {}'.format(
      fine_tune_checkpoint_type))

if fine_tune_checkpoint_type == 'classification':
  return self._feature_extractor.restore_from_classification_checkpoint_fn(
      self._extract_features_scope)

if fine_tune_checkpoint_type == 'detection':
  variables_to_restore = {}
  for variable in tf.global_variables():
    var_name = variable.op.name
    if load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars:
      variables_to_restore[var_name] = variable
    else:
      if var_name.startswith(self._extract_features_scope):
        variables_to_restore[var_name] = variable

return variables_to_restore
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could get correct loss now. BTW，Could you tell me where is the file's location you attached. I wanna modify the network with morphNet. .If you have some suggestion on it please inform me . Thanks